# MySQL returing 1 row with 2 statements

Tags: php, mysql

i want to have this 2 query's as one so that 1 when i run it get 1 row with all the data called ontvanger.
This code below wont work but and i try ed many different one
so i was wondering if i could get some help with this.

```
$getBuddies = dbquery("select sender AS ontvanger FROM messenger_friendships WHERE receiver = '30'");
$getBuddies2 = dbquery("select receiver AS ontvanger FROM messenger_friendships WHERE sender = '30'");

        $i = 0;

        while ($buddy = mysql_fetch_assoc($getBuddies, $getBuddies2));
```

The fix thanks to  **ErichBSchulz**

```
case 'recipients':

    echo '/*-secure-' . LB;
    echo '[';


    $getBuddies = dbquery("select sender AS ontvanger FROM messenger_friendships WHERE receiver = '" . USER_ID . "'
                            UNION select receiver AS ontvanger FROM messenger_friendships WHERE sender = '" . USER_ID . "'");   $i = 0;

    while ($buddy = mysql_fetch_assoc($getBuddies))
    {
        if ($i > 0)
        {
            echo ',';
        }

        echo '{"id":' . $buddy['ontvanger'] . ',"name":"' . clean($users->id2name($buddy['ontvanger'])) . '"}';

        $i++;
    }
```

Comment: You can't just make up new ways to call a function. If it says it takes one query, you can't call it with two queries and expect it to magically figure out what you want.

Comment: What do you want the result to look like? How do you want the two sets of results to be combined into one row? What if each query returns more than 1 row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want something like:

```
$getBuddies = dbquery(
"select sender AS ontvanger FROM messenger_friendships WHERE receiver = '30'
 UNION select receiver AS ontvanger FROM messenger_friendships WHERE sender = '30'");
```

**edit:** of course you could also do this:

```
$getBuddies = dbquery(
"select if(sender = '30', receiver, sender) AS ontvanger 
FROM messenger_friendships 
WHERE receiver = '30' OR sender = '30'");
```

But as Barmar points out both these queries will return multiple rows - but reading between the lines I'm guessing that is what you are actually after.

Then nice thing about the first query is it will remove duplicates.

Comment: This will return 2 rows, not 1 row.

Comment: This one did it nicely. thanks for the very quick help mate ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT sender,receiver FROM messenger_friendships WHERE receiver = '30' OR sender = '30'
```

This will return 1 row with all matching data as long as there aren't several rows with '30'. If so you could use `GROUP_CONCAT()` and get all results returned as a string in 1 row, if you now have to only get 1 row returned by the query.

Comment: in fact there are several rows with the same data. so this one i already tryed but it gives me double data.

Comment: If you have an excess amount of data you could use GROUP BY

Comment: Ok, I guess I misunderstood your question then about returning 1 row.

Comment: no trouble i did ask the question in a manner that its hard to understand my fault.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql does not allow for multiple queries. Mysqli on the other hand offers the possibility to enable [multiple queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).

Comment: Yes, of course. I think in your case union is the way to go. You don't want to change to mysqli for that. But you should consider to change since mysql is deprecated in php 5.5.

Comment: At this moment we use MariaDB and we use php 5.3 our scripts won't support 5.4 or higher. but thanks for the heads up ';) appreciated

Comment: I also still use mysql extension. Mysqli will be for later. I recently upgraded from php 5.2 to 5.4. It took me three weeks to update the script. The changes seem minor, but they had more consequences than expected.